# How do I Insert multiple Contact form7 pre define template when a plugin install?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, contact-form-7

I am developing a contact form7 based plugin. I want when someone installs my plugin to auto-insert multiple contact form7 templates which I will define on my plugin. Like: Contact form 1, Contact form 2 etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Register the "book" custom post type
 */
function pluginprefix_setup_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'book', ['public' => true ] ); 
} 
add_action( 'init', 'pluginprefix_setup_post_type' );
 
 
/**
 * Activate the plugin.
 */
function pluginprefix_activate() { 
    // Trigger our function that registers the custom post type plugin.
    pluginprefix_setup_post_type(); 
    // Clear the permalinks after the post type has been registered.
    flush_rewrite_rules(); 
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'pluginprefix_activate' );
```

It's default hook while activate your plugin.
Contact form 7 creates custom post type with

> wpcf7_contact_form

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/

insert post which ever number of the contact form you want to insert.